# saving return code and returning it in bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to do this in bash

```sh
#!/bin/bash

func(){
    return 1;
}

e=func
echo some text
exit e
```

but I'm getting

```
exit: func: numeric argument required
```

AFAIK variables in bash are without a type, how to "convert" it to int to satisfy requirement?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add a `$` in front of a variable to "dereference" it. Also, you must do this:

```
func
e=$?
# some commands
exit $e
```

`$?` contains the return code of the last executed "command"

Doing `e=func` sets string `func` to variable `e`.

Comment: Thanks, sequence of `func` and `e=$?` did the trick, missing $ was just a typo.